# IdentityServer4 with MIM and ADFS

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, identity, adfs, microsoft-identity-platform

We are trying to implement an Identity & Access Management platform, which will be covering all our applications and services. We have already MIM, ADFS and Azure AD (synchronized internal users)

Number of users probably are around 900 000 (internal in AD and most of them externa in user registeries) and number of applications are around 30, including Office 365, SharePoint 2010, Asp.NET based applications, Java Spring Boot Microservices.

Could IdentityServer4 be a good option with combination of MIM and ADFS to cover all users and applications?

Thank you and appreciate all kind of advice.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the use cases that you envisage.

idsrv4 has both SAML and WS-Fed plugins so can handle all protocols.

It only does authentication not user provisioning. To do that you could look at [AdminUI](https://www.identityserver.com/products/).

Scaling may be an issue?

The fact that it is open source is a big advantage since you can extend functionality via the extension points.

Comment: Thanks, What do you mean scaling may be an issue?

Comment: I meant that you would best run in Azure so you can scale up / out. On-premises not sure how many concurrent connections it can handle?